# Read trackpad system preferences programmatically Mac Os X Mavericks

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks, system-properties, system-preferences

for one of my program, I need to be able to *read* (not write) the user's trackpad system preferences programmatically.

I've read that CFPreferences should be able to help me, but I failed in finding any sample code that would show me how to simply be able to list all the preferences of a specified System preference pane (e.g, trackpad).

How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

sorry it's a little late to answer this post.

The `defaults` command-line tool allows you to configure your system preferences.

If you just want to read the values, type `defaults read`.

You can specify a domain name to be more specific. In your case you want trackpad settings so type `defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad`. 
This will give you all the trackpad settings.

You can also check `man defaults`for more information.